# how to deploy "surveyor" Rails plugin on heroku.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, surveyor-gem

I'm kinda new to this stuff, and I need some help please 
I created my rails app using ruby 1.8.7/rails 2.3.8 
I added Surveyor to the Gemfile. 
I pushed the project to heroku.com using git, went through the normal 
procedure in the "Quick Start" guide on heroku, including

```
$ heroku bundle install 
$ heroku db:migrate
```

and all went through peacefully. But when I try to create a survey 
using:

```
$ heroku rake surveyor FILE=surveys/kitchen_sink_survey.rb
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted! 
uninitialized constant Surveyor
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: I know this question is old, but if there's still a question about this, post a `--trace` of the rake task, and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run `rails generate surveyor:install` before `db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add the gem to your `environment.rb`

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config| 
  config.gem "surveyor"
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I've already done that, but I cannot get the app running/generating surveys from the template, as you see in the error above.